# Find all possible modifications to a graph

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, graph, recursive-datastructures

I am now using lists to represent the graph, which would be similar to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946155/find-out-all-possible-modification-that-can-be-done-to-a-graph). I found out that the dict approach would be very long and complex, so decided to go with the list approach. But I am still facing a few roadblocks.

So for example, the  graph:
[image: Graph]

is now represented as:

```py
nodes = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
edges = [
  [0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 2],
  [1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

Here, edge weights can only be 1 or 2 and 0 represents no edge from one node to other. The edges are directed, so every list in the matrix represents the edges coming toward the node.

Similar to the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946155/find-out-all-possible-modification-that-can-be-done-to-a-graph), I want all possible two-edge modifications on the graph. So, for example, if we add an edge from node "4" to "5" with weight of 1, and remove the edge with weight 1 coming from node "1" to "4", the new graph will look like:

```py
edges = [
  [0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
  [1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
]
```

and this is one of the possible modifications.

I want to build a generator that can create all such modifications sequentially and pass it to me so that I can use them to test.

My code so far is like this:

```py
def all_modification_generation(graph: list[list], iter_count: int = 0):
    possible_weights = {-1, 0, 1}
    node_len = len(graph)
    for i in range(node_len**2):
          ix_x = i // node_len
          ix_y = i % node_len
          if i == ix_y:
              continue
          for possible_pertubs in possible_weights - {graph[ix_x][ix_y]}:
              graph[ix_x][ix_y] = possible_pertubs
              if iter_count == 0:
                  all_modification_generation(graph=graph, iter_count=iter_count + 1)
              else:
                  yield all_modification_generation(graph=graph)
```

My logic is, once I do one change, I can then loop over all other elements that come after it in the matrix. So this problem could be solved recursively. And once a node is explored, we do not need to take it into consideration for next loops, because it will just give us a duplicate result that we have already found. And because I need to check for 2 modifications, I am increasing `iter_count` after first iteration and then yielding the next time. I am skipping `ix_x == ix_y` cases because a self-looping edge does not make any sense in this context, so that change is not required to be recorded.

But even then, this does not output any result. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I think I have figured out a way to do the double modification without repetitive generation of modified matrices. Now the only problem is that there is quite a bit of code repetition and a 4-level nested for-loop.

I'm not sure how to call a generator recursively, but I feel that should be the way to go! Thanks [J_H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8431111/j-h) for pointing me to the right direction.

The working code is:

```
def all_modification_generation(graph: list[list]):
    possible_weights = {-1, 0, 1}
    node_len = len(graph)
    for i in range(node_len**2):
        ix_x1 = i // node_len
        ix_y1 = i % node_len
        if ix_x1 == ix_y1:
            continue
        for possible_pertubs in possible_weights - {graph[ix_x1][ix_y1]}:
            cc1_graph = deepcopy(graph)
            cc1_graph[ix_x1][ix_y1] = possible_pertubs
            for j in range(i + 1, node_len**2):
                ix_x2 = j // node_len
                ix_y2 = j % node_len
                if ix_x2 == ix_y2:
                    continue
                for possible_perturbs2 in possible_weights - {cc1_graph[ix_x2][ix_y2]}:
                    cc2_graph = deepcopy(cc1_graph)
                    cc2_graph[ix_x2][ix_y2] = possible_perturbs2
                    yield cc2_graph
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a "two edge modification"?

Comment: It means only two changes can be done to the graph. So, only 2 elements in the matrix `edge` will change and it will be considered an output. I need to find all such output with only 2 changes to the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic looping is an interesting technique.
We *do* wind up with quite a few repeated
division results, from `// node_len`, but that's fine.

---

I had a "base + edits" datastructure in mind for this problem.

Converting array to list-of-lists would be straightforward.

After overhead, a 5-node graph consumes 25 bytes -- pretty compact.
Numpy offers good support for several styles of sparse
graphs, should that become of interest.

```
from typing import Generator, Optional
import numpy as np


class GraphEdit:
    """A digraph with many base edge weights plus a handful of edited weights."""

    def __init__(self, edge: np.ndarray, edit: Optional[dict] = None):
        a, b = edge.shape
        assert a == b, f"Expected square matrix, got {a}x{b}"
        self.edge = edge  # We treat these as immutable weights.
        self.edit = edit or {}

    @property
    def num_nodes(self):
        return len(self.edge)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.edit.get(item, self.edge[item])

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.edit[item] = value


def as_array(g: GraphEdit) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array([[g[i, j] for j in range(g.num_nodes)] for i in range(g.num_nodes)])


def all_single_mods(g: GraphEdit) -> Generator[GraphEdit, None, None]:
    """Generates all possible single-edge modifications to the graph."""
    orig_edit = g.edit.copy()
    for i in range(g.num_nodes):
        for j in range(g.num_nodes):
            if i == j:  # not an edge -- we don't support self-loops
                continue
            valid_weights = {0, 1, 2} - {g[i, j]}
            for w in sorted(valid_weights):
                yield GraphEdit(g.edge, {**orig_edit, (i, j): w})


def all_mods(g: GraphEdit, depth: int) -> Generator[GraphEdit, None, None]:
    assert depth >= 1
    if depth == 1:
        yield from all_single_mods(g)
    else:
        for gm in all_single_mods(g):
            yield from all_mods(gm, depth - 1)


def all_double_mods(g: GraphEdit) -> Generator[GraphEdit, None, None]:
    """Generates all possible double-edge modifications to the graph."""
    yield from all_mods(g, 2)
```

Here's the associated test suite.

```
import unittest
from numpy.testing import assert_array_equal
import numpy as np
from .graph_edit import GraphEdit, all_double_mods, all_single_mods, as_array


class GraphEditTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.g = GraphEdit(
            np.array(
                [
                    [0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
                    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 1, 0, 2],
                    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                ],
                dtype=np.uint8,
            )
        )

    def test_graph_edit(self):
        g = self.g
        self.assertEqual(5, self.g.num_nodes)
        self.assertEqual(2, g[0, 1])
        g[0, 1] = 3
        self.assertEqual(3, g[0, 1])
        del g.edit[(0, 1)]
        self.assertEqual(2, g[0, 1])

    def test_non_square(self):
        with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
            GraphEdit(np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]))

    def test_all_single_mods(self):
        g = GraphEdit(np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0]]))

        self.assertEqual(4, len(list(all_single_mods(g))))

        expected = [
            np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 2], [1, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 0], [2, 0]]),
        ]

        for ex, actual in zip(
            expected,
            map(as_array, all_single_mods(g)),
        ):
            assert_array_equal(ex, actual)

            # Now verify that original graph is untouched.
            assert_array_equal(
                np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0]]),
                as_array(g),
            )

    def test_all_double_mods(self):
        g = GraphEdit(np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0]]))

        self.assertEqual(16, len(list(all_double_mods(g))))

        expected = [
            np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 2], [1, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 1], [0, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 1], [2, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0]]),  # note the duplicate
            np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]),
            np.array([[0, 2], [0, 0]]),  # and it continues on in this vein
        ]

        for ex, actual in zip(
            expected,
            map(as_array, all_double_mods(g)),
        ):
            assert_array_equal(ex, actual)

    def test_many_mods(self):
        self.assertEqual(40, len(list(all_single_mods(self.g))))
        self.assertEqual(1_600, len(list(all_double_mods(self.g))))
        self.assertEqual(1_600, len(list(all_mods(self.g, 2))))
        self.assertEqual(64_000, len(list(all_mods(self.g, 3))))
        self.assertEqual(2_560_000, len(list(all_mods(self.g, 4))))
```

One could quibble about the fact that
it produces duplicates, since inner and outer loops
know nothing of one another.
It feels like this algorithm wants to use an
[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)
approach, generating all modifications in lexicographic order.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to include a bit more information. Could you check it out and help me out? Also, I'm not sure how the `yield from` works in your answer. I could not find much helpful info from other resources too. Could you please explain?

Comment: Well, as the type annotation explains, it's a generator. Python coroutines (`yield`!) let you produce an unbounded number of results without having to allocate storage for them. The expression `yield from gen()` is similar to these two lines: `for x in gen(): yield x`. https://michaelnorris.com/python-yield-from Generators [compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) very nicely, so I tend to think of them as analagous to unix pipes: `stage1.sh | stage2.sh | stage3.sh | sort | grep foo`